# Can't install python-pandas on ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, python

I am trying install python library `pandas` on ubuntu system, and it seems to work, but it it does not. Here is what I did:

```
sudo pip install pandas
```

This seemed to install `pandas` properly. I got this message:

```
Successfully installed pandas python-dateutil pytz numpy six
Cleaning up...
```

However, when I ran:

```
pip freeze
```

I did not see `pandas` installed. Also, when I tried to `import pandas` in python shell in I couldn't (obviously).

Any ideas what is going wrong? Or what I could do to trouble shoot, and figure out what is going?

I am using `ubuntu 12.04`.

Thank You

Comment: Have you activate a virtualenv when running these commands?

Comment: @OrangeTux, I am in the virtualenv when running these commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `sudo pip install pandas` (with sudo) you use the system wide binary of pip. It is probably located /usr/bin/pip. You should activate your virtualenv and run `pip install pandas`, without sudo. Than you use the pip binary of your virtualenv. Now `pip freeze` will give the expected results.